# Do we need enterprise support for RHEL/CentOS and PostgreSQL

Tags: centos, redhat, java, postgresql

We are an SI currently working on a proposal for an web app solution with tight budget. The 3rd party web app is written in JDK7 is to be deployed to 2 physical server running 3 VM each, one for application, one for database and one for DMZ. All 3 VM are planned to achieve automatic failover. We're predominantly Microsoft based, but due to budget constraint, we're exploring using Linux for the solution. The web app vendor do support RHEL/CentOS + Postgres.

Although we have 2 staffs(myself and another colleague) have been toying with Linux for personal use, i.e. AWS instance and Raspberry Pi, but we don't have adequate resources well verse in Linux/PostgreSQL to support the production environment we planned to propose. Then we started looking for 3rd party support for RHEL and PostgreSQL(EnterpriseDB), we were shocked that the license and support fee is similar to what Microsoft's vendor is charging.

We do understand that OpenSource is the way forward in the long run, and hence we're keen to go with OpenSource solution, but we need to convince our upper management that it's worth the trouble. So we need to find out:

- What is the significance of switching to Linux other than cost

  - our guess is lower hardware requirement
- Do we really need enterprise support? We do have SLA to commit to.

  - Personally I'm not certified in Linux but I've not seen much trouble maintaining CentOS and Ubuntu for my VPS/Cloud instances serving the web, and toying with Raspberry Pi for various home related project. I'm also running Arch Linux full time on my laptop.
  - I'm also under the impression that once properly setup, there shouldn't be much chance for critical failure to come.
- If we went without enterprise support, and if all of the sudden, we're in trouble and needs immediate assistance within hours, is there a chance to get proper support if we're willing to pay by ad hoc basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rarely buy RHEL support. I have worked in environments where all systems were fully-paid RHEL and others where thousands of systems were running the license-free CentOS variant. The maintenance and management overhead was slightly *higher* with paid Red Hat. There was a bit more headache in managing licenses and entitlements and delays in deployment. Again, that was at a large-scale infrastructure provider. But the operational differences between CentOS and RHEL are minimal. I would file 1-2 calls to Red Hat support each year.

I'd recommend that you retain some local Linux expertise (*and possibly a DBA*); either a consultant or hire a Linux administrator. Red Hat is not going to log in and fix your application or have any visibility into your business. They're not going to respond in the timelines that are critical to your application. You pay Red Hat for the right to the OS and to fix bugs and release security patches.

Comment: May I know what kind of issues was raised in that 1-2 calls you made to Red Hat support each year? You're able to file such calls even when you don't buy their support? Btw, any thought on PostgreSQL?

Comment: The issues I've had with Red Hat were serious problems that most people don't see unless they're running specialized hardware or pushing the limits of their systems. My support calls were usually for kernel enhancements or me reporting patches that my team wanted to be incorporated into the new RHEL release. I would never call Red Hat for a "*my system is down*" situation.

Comment: @faulty Did this answer your question?

Comment: I was hopping for more answers to compare with, yours is the closest thus far, thanks again :)